# In C#, is there a way to reference the calling class in a constructor?

Tags: c#, .net

I am making a constructor for a class in c#, and I would like it to fill its values differently depending on the type of class that called it.
For example, there is a class called `Employer` and a class called `Person`.
When an instance of `Employer` calls `new Person();` I would like the constructor in `Person` to set the new person's `Employed` variable to `true`.
Is this possible in c#?

Tried searching for an answer but was unsure how to word the question.

UPDATE: As helpful comments answered, it seems to be impossible for a class or function to directly access its caller without explicitly handing it a reference.

At first I felt that constructors did not quite address my original need, but writing these out helped me understand how they did:

```
public class Person
{
    bool employed = false;

    void setDefaultValues()
    {
        //do stuff
    }

    public Person()//empty constructor
    {
        setDefaultValues();
    }

    public Person(Employer em) //type-safe constructor
    {
        setDefaultValues();
        employed = true;
    }

    public Person(Type ty) //adaptable constructor
    {
        setDefaultValues();
        if (ty == typeOf(Employer))
        {
            employed = true;
        }
    }

}
public class Employer
{
//This person will not be employed
    Person nonemployee = new Person();

//This person will be employed, via type-safe constructor, and its constructor will have access to all of the properties of its caller
    Person employee1 = new Person(this);

//This person will be employed, via adaptable constructor
    Person employee2 = new Person(this.GetType);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it automatically, no. (You *could* grab a stack trace and parse that, but it would be horribly brittle in the face of JIT compiler optimizations etc.) I'd argue that doing so would make the code brittle and hard to maintain, too - the effect would be like "spooky action at a distance".

The simplest option is to add a `bool employed` parameter in the constructor instead. Then it's really obvious at every call site how you want the constructed object to behave.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few different ways to do this. The first is to overload the constructor.

```
public Person() {
   this.Employed = false;
}
public Person(bool employed) {
   this.Employed = employed;
}
```

The second that comes to mind is to populate the expected values when instantiating the object.

```
Person myPerson = new Person {Employed = true };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have `multiple constructors` with different inputs for a class:

```
public Person() {
   this.Employed = false;
}
public Person(bool employed) {
   this.Employed = employed;
}
public Person(bool employed,bool _isEmploye) {
    if(_isEmploye)
        this.Employed = true;
    else
        this.Employed = false;
}
```

and use appropriate inputs wherever you call:

```
Person p = new Person(true,true);
```